# MVC Submit button action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, submit

I have a little problem with Submit button action. I know question is not new and saw many answers for such kind of questions, but still can't understand what is wrong.

View:

```
  <form asp-action="TableSettings">

    <p>Please, select rows count for  tabe in tab "Orders"</p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, Model.Rows)

    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />

  </form>
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(string Submit, MyModel model)
    {
        Settings settings = _context.Settings.FirstOrDefault();

        int id = model.SelectedId;
        settings.Value = id.ToString();
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

After I click the button nothing changed. Just dropdownlist reset. That's all.

P.S. Please, don't beat me ))

Comment: You have `asp-action="TableSettings` which posts back to a `TableSettings()` method. (the method you have shown is named `Submit()`)

Comment: `asp-action="Submit"` probably is what you want as target action method receives POST request.

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in your controller. Then if it doesn't get hit, it becomes pretty obvious that the problem is it's the wrong action. Learn to debug and you will get far

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks! I'm too inattentive. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in wrong asp-action name. Thanks everyone. Next time I will check everything more attentively.

Should be

```
asp-action="Submit"
```